# How to streamline a proof of a function property on a datatype?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I have created a small proof with the intention of creating an example for using `next` on proof cases:

```
theory RedGreen 

imports Main 

begin 

datatype color = RED | GREEN 

fun green :: "color => color" 
where 
  "green RED   = GREEN" 
| "green GREEN = GREEN" 

lemma disj_not: "P \<or> Q \<Longrightarrow> \<not>P \<longrightarrow> Q" 
proof 
  assume disj: "P \<or> Q" 
  assume "\<not>P" 
  from this show "Q" using `P \<or> Q` by (simp) 
qed   

lemma redgreen: "x \<noteq> RED \<longrightarrow> x = GREEN" 
proof  
  assume notred: "x \<noteq> RED" 
  have "x = RED \<or> x = GREEN" by (simp only: color.nchotomy)  
  from this show "x = GREEN" using notred by (simp add:  disj_not) 
qed 

lemma "green x = GREEN" 
proof cases 
  assume "x = RED" 
  from this show "green x = GREEN" by (simp) 
next 
  assume "x \<noteq> RED" 
  from this have "x = GREEN" by (simp add: redgreen) 
  from this show "green x = GREEN" by (simp) 
qed
```

Can this be streamlined without losing the details? Using some magical tricks would not be the thing I wish for. Improving the style of using Isar is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that such low-level (and ad-hoc) rules like your `disj_not` and `redgreen` are hardly ever useful. If they are really necessary this can most likely be attributed to some lack of automation (via appropriate `simp`, `intro`, `elim`, and `dest` rules). Gladly, in your example these "intermediate lemmas" are not necessary at all (and I do not think that they are of special educational value). Coming to your question of a streamlined version. I think one canonical way of doing so would be the following:

```
lemma "green x = GREEN"
proof (cases x)
  case RED
  then show "green x = GREEN" by simp
next
  case GREEN
  then show "green x = GREEN" by simp
qed
```

Where the automatically generated fact `color.exhaust` is used for a proof by cases on the variable `x` of type `color`.

Comment: Another stylistic suggestion I would make is that you can say `then show ?thesis by simp`, which avoids some of the duplication. `?thesis` is simply shorthand for the original statement you were trying to prove.

Comment: @davidg: you are of course right. For readability (if there are short goals) I sometimes explicitly write show statements. In a real development the above would be proved via `by (cases x) simp_all` anyway ;)